# Satis - SVN HTTP authentication option

Tags: php, svn, composer-php, satis, packagist

Satis Docs:

- http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

I see the option for GIT authentication via SSH and SSL but would I wanted to know what about basic HTTP authentication?

Does Satis support this and if so where is the documentation?

Do I use something like this?

```
svn co http://<url>/<repo> <local_dir> --username user --password password
```

So I have this:

```
{
    "name": "Local Packagist",
    "homepage": "http://blah/packagist",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "http://blahsvn/myProject/my-bundle" }
    ],
    "require-all": true
}
```

How do I add the authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For svn, it should ask you for a password if you run interactively, and offer you to cache it or not.

Comment: yes it does but could this be configured as a authentication option as I have several ( over 30 custom bundles ) I've added and each one requires my user/pass/cache option. And if the cache option is to handle the user/pass it's not working correctly then

Comment: If you enter `yes` at the cache prompt, it should let svn write it in the system cache (i.e. it won't run with --no-auth-cache), so following calls should work fine. If all of them are on different repos though I guess you'll have to enter your password a bunch of times yes. At the moment we don't have any better option, you can always report an issue for it, but tbh given that svn is kind of "legacy", these issues are generally not high prio. Meaning either you do it or it might take a long time for me to get to it :)

Comment: yeah I'm pushing for GIT but it's a slow process, sigh... Thanks for the help